# How do you write $\sin(2x)$ in terms of $\tan x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to write $\sin 2x$ in terms of $\tan x$. Here is my progress so far:

$$\begin{align}\sin 2x &= 2\sin x\cos x\\
&=2\tan x\cos^2x\\
&=2\tan x \cdot \frac{1+\cos2x}2\\
&=\tan x(1+\cos2x)\\
&=\tan x\cot^2x \cdot (1-\cos2x)\\
&=\frac{1-\cos2x}{\tan x}\end{align}$$

As it seems, I cannot seem to fully convert everything into $\tan x$. These are not all my steps, as I try many other things, but it always results in extra $\cos2x$, $\cos^2x$, or some other trig function that wont easily convert into $\tan x$. I need some insight on how to continue.

Comment: Hint: $\,\tan^2 x + 1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\,$.

Comment: This is also known as weirstrauss substitution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sin2x&=2\sin x\cos x\\
&=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{1}\\&=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}\\&\small\text{(Divide both numerator and denominator by $\cos^2x$)}\\&=\frac{2\tan x}{\tan^2x+1}\qquad\small\left(\because\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: oh wow i wouldve never thought of that in a million years...